# Python numpy array index slicing with n number of :(colons)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wish to achieve something like this.
Input:

1. `x`, which is an np array
2. `i`, an integer

I want to get the result of `x[:, <in total i number of :'s>, 1, :, :, <infinite :'s>]`
Where number `1` is at index `i` of the selection tuple.

For example, if `i = 3`, I wish to get the result of `x[:, :, :, 1, ...]`

Couldn't find any solutions online. Thank you very much.

Comment: `np.take` is simplest, though it isn't hard to construct a slicing `tuple`.  You don't need the trailing `...`, that's automatic.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html is a good resource.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. I'm wondering how the slicing tuple can be constructed?

Comment: You can use tuple methods, repeat and join to make a new tuple: `(slice(None),)*2 + (1,)`.  Sometimes it's easier to create (and modify) a list or array, and then convert that to a tuple.